# "Proposition" vs. "The Meaning of a Proposition"

Tags: logic, semantics

Do the terms "proposition" and "meaning of the proposition" mean the same thing?

Put differently: let *P* denote a proposition.  Do the terms *P* and "the meaning of *P*" **mean** the same thing?  Do they **denote** the same thing?

Comment: Sorry, if this sounds _utterly_ sophistic: By 'meaning' do you mean something like 'relevance, importance', or do you mean something like 'content, intension'?

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can understand the term ***proposition*** as:

> **1**. The string of symbols that forms a truth-bearer sentence, a declarative sentence.
>
> **2**. The "meaning" (or the content) of a declarative sentence.

Different authors used the same term in different sense of words, so it can be confusing.

To avoid confusion, we can use the term *statement* (or just *sentence*) to refer **(1)**, as it is done in mathematical logic, and the term *proposition* to refer **(2)**.

See Strawson's article: [*On referring*](http://www.eecoppock.info/Presupposition/Readings/strawson50.pdf) (1950, this is a critique of Russell's Theory of descriptions)

Answer (score 1):

When considering questions such as this, it is useful to keep in mind Frege's ontology { concept, object, name }.  Everything is considered as being in these three categories.

We give an object a name (denotation), here **P**.  In turn, the object has a concept (or sense).

If you are familiar with modern computer languages (object-oriented programming), then this should be natural to you as the ontology { class, object, name }, where the object is a named instance of the class.

On the other hand, in a different context both *object* and *name* are concepts which can be instantiated as an object with a name.  So it is important to keep context in mind.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, but I think might depend on the author. Following Russell's way, propositions are just values for propositional functions, so you need to understand this also. I.e, a proposition is the same as the fact which the *statement* represents; for example, "Socrates is a man" is the same proposition as "Socrates é um homem", although they are different statements, i.e, different chains of signs in different languages with different syntaxes and grammars. All propositions are true or false. A propositional functions would be a incomplete pseudo-statement that it's not true or false in virtue of some missing semantic aspect. For example, "x is a man" is a propositional function (I said "pseudo-statement" because "x is a man" is the same as "x é um homem", although they are not propositions) represents a function whose values are propositions, and the domain is the class of all man. So the "x" is some kind of "hole" inside that statement, which, when fulfilled, assumes a proposition false or true.

If you want a very better explanation, see what Russell wrote about it in
http://www.users.drew.edu/~jlenz/br-on-propositions.pdf

and the chapter about propositional functions in

https://archive.org/details/principlesofmath005807mbp

A more simple and less philosophical explanation can be found in the beginning of
https://archive.org/details/PrincipiaMathematicaVolumeI

I would also recommend everything you could find on Frege about the subject, especially
http://fitelson.org/proseminar/frege_fac.pdf

I hope it helps, have a nice day.